# Nginx Server Block Not Working? - Already running other vhosts just this one not working

Tags: linux, nginx, debian-squeeze

Im running a Debian 6 LEMP server with multiple virtual hosts and everything has been fine for 5 or so sites. But I've just tried adding another but for some reason it's just not working. By not working I mean in Chrome I get the "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to subdomain.domain.net" error.

I've changed the domain for security to **subdomain.example.com** and the IP is masked.

Hosts file (I have multiple sub domains):

```
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx *.example.com *.example
```

Server Block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     subdomain.example.com;

    access_log      /srv/www/subdomain.example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log       /srv/www/subdomain.example.com/logs/error.log;
    root            /srv/www/subdomain.example.com/public_html;

    location / {
        index       index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {     
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

I've created the system link to the file in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` directory and restarted/reloaded nginx.

DNS seems fine:

```
# ping -c 2 subdomain
PING subdomain.example.com (xxx.xxx.xx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www.example.com (xxx.xxx.xx.xxx): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
64 bytes from www.example.com (xxx.xxx.xx.xxx): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
```

Checking the file with cURL works:

```
# curl http://subdomain.example.com
HTML - OK
```

Emptied browser cache but still no dice.

Anything I'm missing? Like I mentioned, I have a few sites running fine on the server currently so php-fpm etc etc are working. Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person who set up the domain for me pointed it to the wrong server IP so that was the issue.

Schoolboy error, sorry to have bothered you all!

On a side note, the *.domain.com references in the hosts file do actually work.

Answer (score 1):

its kind of hard to help you out there, as you didn't provide enough information... but I'll try it anyway

- hosts file doesn't support masking so you can't use "*." in your hosts file.
- that ping that you did it came from where? server or client?
- for curl use -v to check your host/IP
- does your chrome have some sort of proxy enabled? that would possible route you somehow different from what you're expecting..

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply. hmm its odd you mention the hosts file not supporting the *. as I've setup a few sites now using that and they work fine? the ping was from the server but ive traced the domain back to the server using a client also. i'll have a go with the other curl and by hardcoding in the host on Monday though. thanks again for your help, Dave

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, is there any other info that would help shine some light on the situation that you can think of?